# Java heap dump - java.lang.Thread is the top component

Tags: java, jboss, heap-dump, thread-dump

I have got the heap dumps by using jmap. I loaded it in eclipse MAT. 
java.lang.Thread is the top consumer. When I clicked on the immediate dominator, it shows a ArrayList with 17K objects(org.jboss.security.SecurityAssociation$SubjectContext) in it.

I took heap dumps at different time(2 hours interval).

java.lang.Thread @ 0xd09f05d0  pool-7-thread-1 Thread  112 |    12,198,024 |      7.64%

java.lang.Thread @ 0xd09e64c8  pool-7-thread-1 Thread  112 |    19,037,464 |      8.58%

Shallow Heap : 112
Retained Heap: 19,037,464
Percentage 8.58

Heap size is increasing.

The thread objects(0xd09f05d0 ,0xd09e64c8 ) are different, thread name is same(pool-7-thread-1). 
Is it still referring the same thread and its heap grows? Or one thread (0xd09f05d0  ) is completed its operation and the same thread with different object (0xd09e64c8  ) is used for different operation and it is holding different objects?

Comment: Can you tell what is the pool implementation you use?

Comment: `DefaultThreadFactory` used by standard JDK `Executors`, according to its' source, must not reassign name to the thread. Have you application been restarted between the moments dumps were taken?

Comment: I did not restart the application. How can I check the pool implementation?

Comment: By looking into source code of pool you use.